# Creating a struct and a class with the same name

Tags: c++

**Summary**: What happens if you declare a `struct` and a `class` with the same name.

**Details**:

I'm reviewing some code and I saw a warning like this:

```
warning: struct 'foo' was previously declared as a class
```

When compiling with clang there were also a couple of places where clang added notes saying:

```
foo.h:29:1: note: did you mean struct here?
class foo;
^~~~~
struct
```

Obviously this is not a good coding practice to have a struct and a class with the same name.  It looks like what happened is the developer was writing his own class and used a name that was already in use in another file that he was including and he did not notice that.

However, my question is will the compiler be able to tell the difference between the variables that were declared as `class foo` and the ones that were `struct foo`?

**Edit**:

Actually what was happening was that the developer was using the `class foo` in a `class bar` that he had created.  I think that in the meantime the place where the `class foo` was declared had been changed to a `struct bar`.  So that was why the code was compiling.  So I guess the answer to my question is that `struct` and `class` are interchangeable when declaring objects.  Still I guess it's a good idea to use them consistently.

Comment: No, they're the same thing, apart from a couple accessibility aspects.

Comment: No. The code shouldn't even compile. It's possible that your compiler just does the correction (based on the assumption described in the Warning message).

Comment: And the warning is junk.  There's absolutely no problem with declaring `class Foo;`, then defining `struct Foo;`, or vice versa.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious What violates the one definition rule?

Comment: @Bee Wrong... sort of. You can declare a type as `class`, `struct` or `union` and then use a different one for the definition. Multiple definitions shouldn't compile.

Comment: I suggest a good book on physical design of code.

Comment: @JamesKanze Ouch. Misread part of the post.

Comment: @JamesKanze Maybe there is no syntactical problem but it *might* be a semantical problem. Can create a lot of confusion and even incorrect behavior (when in fact forwarding a different type than the one intended)

Comment: @icepack Most places I've worked have had coding guidelines which specify when you should use `struct`, and when `class`, depending on the role the class has in the application, how it is used, etc.  That's valid for the definition, and for many declarations, but there is a small class of functions which just pass a pointer through, and those _shouldn't_ know whether the class corresponds to what requires `struct` or not.  In those functions, it would be appropriate to always use `class` (or always `struct`), regardless of how the class is actually defined.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm not arguing about all of this. Just saying that using `struct` in declaration and `class` in definition might result in forwarding the `struct` with the same name (yes, it's probably not good practice, but it can happen, and compiler should help the developer, not the other way around) that is defined in the closest `namespace` scope instead of the `class` that you need from out of `namespace`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keywords `struct` and `class` are largely interchangeable.
Even if you write `struct Foo`, you have created a *class* type
with the name of `Foo`.  And that name must be unique within its
scope (with a special exception for reasons of C compatibility,
but which it is better to ignore).

Comment: I'll bite. @James - what is the exception that permit duplicate names within the same scope?

Comment: @Uri §3.3.1/4: "Given a set of declarations in a single
declarative region, each of which specifies the same unqualified
name, [...] - exactly one declaration shall declare a class name
or enumeration name that is not a typedef name and the other
declarations shall all refer to the same variable or enumerator,
or all refer to functions and function templates; in this case
the class name or enumeration name is hidden."  This is present
_only_ for reasons of C compatibility, so 
you can include, for example, `<sys/stat.h>`, which defines
a function `stat` and a `struct stat`.

Answer (score 3):

In general all identifiers must be unique.

In particular, in Section 10.2.8 of the book "The C++ Programming Language", Bjarne Stroustrup states:

> By definition a `struct` is a class in which members are public by
>   default; that is
>
> ```
> struct s { ...
> ```
>
> is simply shorthand for
>
> ```
> class s { public:...
> ```

There is no *underlying difference* between `struct` and `class`; the former is mere syntactic sugar.

So, even if you could have identifiers with the same name (which, again, you cannot), there would be no distinction whatsoever between a struct and a class because they are the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers must be unique, no matter what if you are defining a class or a struct.

Answer (score 1):

I would take @Alex Chamberlain and @James Kanze's comments as an answer:

There is nothing wrong with the code because **declaration != definition**: You can declare a type as a `class`, `struct` or `union` and then use a different one for the definition. Multiple definitions shouldn't compile; multiple declarations however is just fine.

The real problem: When you forward declare, you do NOT want to care whether it was a struct, class or union: In that context, that is an irrelevant implementation detail, that could even change later. So this warning is an artificial code smell. Still, you have to choose, and considering that `class foo;` has come to be *the way to forward declare*, I would go as far as to say **the code is perfect**.

The author didn't *forget* to update the forward declaration; he isn't *supposed to* (whether he changed the implementation or not, he probably didn't).