# C++ Duplicate definition in libraries

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm attempting to build a library using the DNG SDK and LibRaw (which can use the DNG SDK).  When I build both I get a series of duplicate definition errors:

```
In file included from libraw.h:43:0,
                 from imageprocessor.cpp:4:
libraw_internal.h:178:8: error: previous definition of 'class tiff_tag'
 struct tiff_tag {
        ^
In file included from imageprocessor.cpp:5:0: 
dng_image_writer.h: In constructor 'tag_data_ptr::tag_data_ptr(uint16, uint16, uint32, const void*)':
dng_image_writer.h:144:17: error: no matching function for call to 'tiff_tag::tiff_tag(uint16&, uint16&, uint32&)'
    , fData (data)
                 ^
dng_image_writer.h:144:17: note: candidates are:
In file included from libraw.h:43:0,
                 from imageprocessor.cpp:4:
libraw_internal.h:178:8: note: tiff_tag::tiff_tag()
 struct tiff_tag {
        ^
libraw_internal.h:178:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided
libraw_internal.h:178:8: note: constexpr tiff_tag::tiff_tag(const tiff_tag&)
libraw_internal.h:178:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
libraw_internal.h:178:8: note: constexpr tiff_tag::tiff_tag(tiff_tag&&)
libraw_internal.h:178:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
```

My code doesn't use DNG yet, simply adding:

`#include <dng_image_writer.h>`

was enough to generate the error.  C++ is not my strong suit, is there a way to manage these conflicts without modifying either library?

Conflicting declarations:

**dng_image_writer.h:144:**

```
tag_data_ptr (uint16 code,
                      uint16 type,
                      uint32 count,
                      const void *data)

            :   tiff_tag (code, type, count)

            ,   fData (data)

            {
            }
```

**libraw_internal.h:178**

```
struct tiff_tag {
  ushort tag, type;
  int count;
  union { char c[4]; short s[2]; int i; } val;
};
```

**Edit add DNG:tiff_tag declaration**

```
class tiff_tag
    {

    protected:

        uint16 fCode;

        uint16 fType;

        uint32 fCount;

    protected:

        tiff_tag (uint16 code,
                  uint16 type,
                  uint32 count)

            :   fCode  (code)
            ,   fType  (type)
            ,   fCount (count)

            {
            }

    public:

        virtual ~tiff_tag ()
            {
            }

        uint16 Code () const
            {
            return fCode;
            }

        uint16 Type () const
            {
            return fType;
            }

        uint32 Count () const
            {
            return fCount;
            }

        void SetCount (uint32 count)
            {
            fCount = count;
            }

        uint32 Size () const
            {
            return TagTypeSize (Type ()) * Count ();
            }

        virtual void Put (dng_stream &stream) const = 0;

    private:

        // Hidden copy constructor and assignment operator.

        tiff_tag (const tiff_tag &tag);

        tiff_tag & operator= (const tiff_tag &tag);

    };
```

Let me know if any other code would be useful.  Thanks.

Comment: does the `tag_data_ptr` have a member called `tiff_tag` or is it inherited from `tiff_tag` ?

Comment: It seem like you have class named `tiff_tag` with in the same scope as `struct tiff_tag`. May be [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220577/creating-a-struct-and-a-class-with-the-same-name)